# macOS 11: Changing a NSSplitViewItem's NSTitlebarSeparatorStyle does not update immediately

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, macos-big-sur, nssplitviewcontroller

If you change the `titlebarSeparatorStyle` property of a `NSSplitViewItem`, the window does not update immediately. You have to set the focus to another app first for the window to update. However the window isn’t update correctly either. For example the shadow never really gets applied. It works if you set the property in the storyboard. But if you want to change it programatically, it does not work as expected.

I would expect something like the Finder in Big Sur: If you display the content of a Finder window as symbols, there is no shadow or line below the toolbar. If you switch to another view (like column view) a line is being added and the toolbar becomes transparent.

I have added an example project to demonstrate the issue.

[GitHub: SplitViewItem-titlebarSeperator](https://github.com/Iomegan/SplitViewItem-titlebarSeperator)
[image]

**macOS 11.0.1 Beta (20B5012d)**

**Xcode Version 12.2 beta 3 (12B5035g)**

https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4949260923568128

Comment: Hi Daniel, I tested your example project with the latest macOS 11.2.3 and Xcode 12.5 β2, and the issue doesn't seem to be fixed. I run into a similar one, and it looks that it's related: https://github.com/structuredpath/AppleBugReports/tree/master/FB9056229 Have you found any workarounds?

Comment: No workaround so far, sorry.

Comment: The issue has now been fixed with macOS 11.3 (20E232)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up! Even though I managed to squeeze in a dirty workaround for 11.2, I can confirm that the issue is gone on macOS 11.3.1 (20E241).